# Dropping an item on a sortable list that only has excluded items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have several sortable lists connected together, so I can drag one item from one list and put it in another. Every list also has one item at its bottom that is neither sortable nor a drop target, making it impossible to drop any items below it.

That's the intended use, I want the excluded item at the bottom of each list to always stay at the bottom.

Problem is if I empty a list, say I drag out all of its items and place them in another list, so that all that is left is the non-sortable item. If I then drag a new item into it it will always go to the bottom, below my non-sortable, not-a-drop-target item.

**Is it possible, when dropping an new item into a sortable list that only has one non-sortable, not-a-drop-target, item, to have it be placed at the top of the list?**

Example code:

```
$('.segment ol').sortable({
  connectWith: '.segment ol',
  distance: 25,
  items: 'li:not(.disabled)'
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="segment">
      <ol>
        <li>word word word</li>
        <li>word word word</li>
        <li class="disabled">must stay at bottom</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="segment">
      <ol>
        <li class="disabled">must stay at bottom</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

If you were to drag a "word word word" **li** to the other list it would get appended below the disabled **li**.

Comment: Please post some sample html, and the jquery code you have tried

Comment: Done. Thing is it's not a bug, it's just the default way that sortable lists work, I'd like to know if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "receive" event on the sortable list (when you supply options), and do something like this:

```
$('.segment ol').sortable({
    connectWith: '.segment ol',
    distance: 25,
    items: 'li:not(.disabled)',
    over: function(event,ui){ ui.placeholder.insertBefore($(this).children('li.disabled:first')); }
});
```

That will make the currently dragged element prepend itself onto the list (prepend and prependTo will effectively move an item unless you clone it first).

Comment: Right. Thank you. The problem I have with this is that when you are dragging the item the placeholder will still be shown below the disabled item. So that's where it would be expected to land. I'm hoping for a more user-friendly solution.

Comment: Ah ok, that should fix it then. Now when you move an item to a connected sortable list, it should insert the placeholder before the first disabled li.

Comment: Hmm, except now, when you first hover over the drop area, the placeholder will be at the bottom, even if you are at the top.  It will eventually move to the right spot once you move in the list.

Comment: Yes. That should work. I just figured it myself, your initial answer definitely put me on the right track. Here's what I'll be using: `over: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.prependTo(ui.placeholder.parent()); }` Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could fix this by adding `if($(this).children().length == 2) { }` around your `insertBefore()`.  It would be 2 because of the static item plus the placeholder.

Comment: Thanks @JeffB. `if ($(this).children().length == 2) { $(this).prepend(ui.placeholder); }` is indeed the complete answer to the problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more on the hack side of things, but you could add a sortable item to the top of each list that is 0px tall or `display: none`.  This will force the item to get sorted after that item instead of your un-sortable item.

```
<ol>
    <li class="hidden"></li>
    <li>word word word</li>
    <li>word word word</li>
    <li class="disabled">must stay at bottom</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPM7V/2/

Comment: I like this better, actually. That way I don't have to worry about quirks in my manual override of the placeholder, as the other answer suggests. Once there's an item in the list, I want it to be 100% default. This route accomplishes that. I remove the hidden li on drop, and add it to any list that's empty after the move. Thanks for the idea.